# Weblogic error: ServletContainerAdapter manager not initialized correctly

Tags: jdeveloper, weblogic-10.x

I am new in Weblogic server, I am using Jdeveloper along with weblogic, but after launch the weblogic server i got the following error.

> ServletContainerAdapter manager not initialized correctly

I am unable to run any  web application. Please help me how to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I googled about this topic and always get these adviced:

- This error can be safely ignored in the development environment
- change log4j.properties

Please check following property:

> WL_HOME\server\lib\consoleapp\consolehelp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties

The first copy this file for back-up. After try to set following adjust:

> log4j.logger.org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.AdapterManager
>   = FATAL

---

The [weblogic documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wloc10/notes/known_resolved.html) say:

> This message is emitted from one of the frameworks used by the console
>   and can be ignored.

Comment: Please shutdown the weblogic and restart the Jdeveloper completely. If still it exists, then the workspace of the JDeveloper needs to be changed